# Getting a ListView cell object to increment on construction

Tags: java, android, listview, object, adapter

So I'm trying to make a simple prioritized todo list in android studio. I created a hard coded list to test out, the list cell contents are just an integer for priority and a string for the message. I was having trouble getting the cells to populate. I've finally got it to the point where the list populates on the screen but I can't figure out how to get the priority to auto-increment after/during every object construction. I just get all 1's. I think I'm unclear on the process that happens during cell population, or perhaps I don't fully understand basic constructers. Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated. Sorry about all the Log.d's I really don't understand adapters fully and was having trouble figuring out the right syntax.

This is the Cell object

```
public class CellContent {
    private int priority = 0;
    private String itemContent;

    public CellContent(String itemContent)
    {
        priority+=1;
        this.itemContent = itemContent;
    }

    public String getItemContent() {
        return itemContent;
    }

    public void setItemContent(String itemContent) {
        this.itemContent = itemContent;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority=priority;

    }
}
```

This is the List to contain the cells

```
public class ListDataSource {

    private ArrayList<CellContent> todoList;

    public ListDataSource() {
        todoList = new ArrayList<CellContent>();
        setupToDoList();
        Log.d("ListDataSource", "ListDataSource object created");
    }

    public void setupToDoList()
    {
        todoList.add(new CellContent("Wash Dishes"));
        todoList.add(new CellContent("Do Laundry"));
        todoList.add(new CellContent("Clean Bathroom"));
        todoList.add(new CellContent("Sweep and Mop"));
        todoList.add(new CellContent("Walk Dog"));
    }
    public int getPriority(int position)
    {
        return todoList.get(position).getPriority();
    }

    public String getItemContent(int position)
    {
        return todoList.get(position).getItemContent();
    }

    public int getDataSourceLength()
    {
        return todoList.size();
    }
}
```

This is the Adapter

```
public class ListDataSourceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context myContext;
        private LayoutInflater myInflater;
        private ListDataSource myDataSource;

        public ListDataSourceAdapter(Context ctx, ListDataSource ds)
        {
            Log.d("ListDataSourceAdapter","Attempting to create ListDataSourceAdapter");
            myContext = ctx;
            myDataSource = ds;
            myInflater = (LayoutInflater)myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Log.d("ListDataSourceAdapter","ListDataSourceAdapter created successfully");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return myDataSource.getDataSourceLength();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0)
        {
            return myDataSource.getItemContent(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return myDataSource.getPriority(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Log.d("getView","Attempting getView");
            TextView priority;
            TextView itemContent;
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                Log.d("getView", "Attempting to inflate cell");
                convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, parent, false);
            }
            Log.d("getView","attempting to link TextView priority");
            priority = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPriority);
            Log.d("getView","link established, Attempting to set text for priority");
            priority.setText(String.valueOf((myDataSource.getPriority(position))));
            Log.d("getView", "attempting to link TextView listContent");
            itemContent = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtListContent);
            Log.d("getView","link established, Attempting to set text for listContent");
            itemContent.setText(myDataSource.getItemContent(position));
            Log.d("getView","Successfully executed getView");
            return convertView;
        }
}
```

And last but not least, this is my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListDataSource ds;
    private ListView listViewToDo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("MainActivity","Attempting to create data source");
        try {
            ds = new ListDataSource();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("MainActivity","Failed to create data source");
        }
        Log.d("Main Activity","Attempting to link empty list view to on screen view");
        listViewToDo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listOfLists);
        Log.d("Main Activity","Views linked, Attempting to set adapter to listView");
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(new ListDataSourceAdapter(this, ds));
        Log.d("Maing Activity","Successfully set Adapter");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`priority` is an instance field. Every instance of your `CellContent` has its own `priority`; each one is initialized to zero, and then incremented by 1 in the constructor. One instance of `CellContent` does not know the contents of any other instance of `CellContent`, they are completely independent, thus each instance reports it has a priority of 1.

The behavior you are looking for requires a static field. Static fields are shared by all instances of the enclosing type and are initialized only once when the class is first used:

```
private static int priorityCounter = 0; // shared by all instances
private int priority; // only this instance

public CellContent(...) {
    priority = ++priorityCounter;
    ...
}
```

Now each creation of `CellContent` increments a shared counter and sets its `priority` to that value.

Comment: It's worth noting this is not thread-safe. If you are creating `CellContent` instances on multiple threads, it is possible to have more than one instance with the same `priority`. To make it thread safe, you should use an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe it was that simple. But yeah, that did the trick. Thank you.